# Return each Array Value into Variable

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to recover all values from an array like this:

```
$var = array($jogo1_t1, $jogo1_t2, $jogo2_t1, $jogo2_t2, $jogo3_t1, $jogo3_t2);
```

How to export each value into a different variable?

For example:

```
$var1 = FIRST ARRAY VALUE
$var2 = SECOND ARRAY VALUE
$var3 = THIRD ARRAY VALUE
```

Comment: Why would you actually want to do this?

Comment: list($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6) = array($jogo1_t1, $jogo1_t2, $jogo2_t1, $jogo2_t2, $jogo3_t1, $jogo3_t2);

Comment: Maybe with [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use [`list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
list($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6) = $var;
```

or simply use the array keys:

```
$var1 = $var[0];
$var2 = $var[1];
$var3 = $var[2];
$var4 = $var[3];
$var5 = $var[4];
$var6 = $var[5];
```

or if you must, use dynamic variable names (this would work if `$var` was any size without having to rewrite the code):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++) {
    $variableName = 'var' . ($i + 1);
    $$variableName = $var[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need list(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

`$array = array($jogo1_t1, $jogo1_t2, $jogo2_t1, $jogo2_t2, $jogo3_t1, $jogo3_t2); list($var1,$var2) = $array;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$var1 = $var[0];
$var2 = $var[1];
$var3 = $var[2];
// ...etc
```